# VSFTP server giving access denied for new users

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

I am probably missing something simple but I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now and I'm hoping someone can help.

The Setup:

- vsftpd running on a Centos machine a number of existing users have
- access no problem created two new users and those users can't log in
- for some reason

Troubleshooting Notes:

- I can successfully log in as an existing user no problem
- If I try to log in as an existing user with a known bad password I get the anticipated authentication failure in the secure log
- I DO NOT get authentication failures in the secure log for the new users if I use the correct password but the client gets an Access Denied.
- If I log in with a bad password I get the same behavior from the client side, but see the authentication failure in the secure log
- There are no errors in the vsftpd.log
- If I log in as one of the new users through a shell I have full access to their home directory as expected

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on, or where to look next for hints?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  It turns out that I had created the new users with /bin/nologin as their default shell instead of /sbin/nologin and PAM was refusing access because of the unknown shell.